# Peano's Postulates Proofs

Tags: logic, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

How can I prove the following two questions:

Prove using Peano's Postulates for the Natural Numbers that if a and b are two natural numbers such that a + b = a, then b must be 0?

Prove using Peano's Postulates for the Natural Numbers that if a and b are natural numbers then: a + b = 0 if and only if a = 0 and b = 0?

I understand the basic postulates, but not sure how to apply them to these specific questions. The questions seem so basic and obvious, but when it comes to applying the postulates I am lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use induction on $a$ for the first. Use case analysis (4 cases: $a = Z$ or $Sx$, $b = Z$ or $Sy$) for the second.

Comment: I think I figured out the first one, but this answer hasn't really clarified anything for me.